# WordPress/Digital Ocean mysql password reset (difficult scenario) I'm stumped

Tags: mysql, wordpress, passwords, digital-ocean

Before I start I'd like to state that I know very little about SQL so bear with me please.

I recently signed up for hosting with digital ocean, I make WordPress websites so I created a droplet and everything was in working order, had my blog running and everything... Last week I made some tweaks to my blog, one of them being the change of username and password. Im usually always logged into my admin panel but I restarted my PC and now I cant get into my admin panel (I've forgotten the username and password.) I tried every option available to me on http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password (even the emergency.php) but to no avail. The usual password reset email is not working so I figure its because the host is running an ssh server and that causes some interference with the email system.. anyway the only option left that I haven't tried for password reset is the phpmyadmin option, now this is a whole new thing with digital ocean for me. They don't have a cpanel so everything is done via ssh; I was able to figure out the gist of it, and attempted to create a database - now here is where it got tricky... (Since my blog was already up and running shouldn't it already have a database?) Every time I try to create a new SQL username/pass it succeeds in doing so, but then when I attempt to use that password to login to my shell I get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It makes no sense to me because I've just created the username and password yet it does not let me login with it. I am honestly beyond confused and THE ONLY REASON I EVEN WANT TO ACCESS PHPmyadmin IS JUST SO I CAN VIEW MY USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO LOGIN TO MY WORDPRESS ADMIN PANEL.

If anyone has an alternative for me to retrieve my username (even just my username would be fine because then I could use the emergency.php option) or how to get into phpmyadmin I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you so much for your time and efforts in advance, this is very difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about granting permissions to your MySQL users.  From Digital Ocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql):

CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';

Rather than trying to read your password, which is most likely encrypted, you should try to change it.

use mysql;
update user set password = password('new-password') where user = 'you';

From your question it looks like you might also be digging for a Wordpress password.  I'm not as familiar with that, but I can at least give you some basic guidelines:
show databases (see a list of the databases.  try to pick the one that seems logical)
use myWordpressSite;
show tables (see a list of all the tables in that database)
describe thisTableOfInterest; (will display the columns and field types)
select someColumn from thisTableOfInterest;

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! This is great information though from my understanding if I have access to the root would I not have all permissions anyway?

Comment: With MySQL when you create a new user you always have to grant that user permissions (or else that user doesn't have any).  Can you please clarify for me which password you are trying to change?  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, well I am unable to create a new user within the shell because every time I input CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; I get a bash saying the command is invalid. Also [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) is the link that I used when attempting to setup MySQL, but when I did I always got stuck on  [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0002gkty32) step because I was unable to login to MySQL.

Comment: The confusing part for me is that my site was already up and running, so a database already existed right? I mean if wordpress was already up and running is it even necessary for me to install SQL? Like I said im very new to this so its just speculation. Please let me know if I have confused you... and once again thank you for time and help!